# Is there a way to set mobile/cell view to desktop?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is there a way to set mobile/cell view to desktop view? I've seen sites have a switch between mobile and desktop view, can Joomla! be set to desktop view as default?

Comment: Im not sure why you'd want to do this. You're simply destroying the user experience

Comment: Joomla does not have mobile/desktop modes out of the box. This is something that would be implemented in the template or with plugins.

Comment: I see the comments from the other community mates here, but personally I feel that this question is a bit unclear, vague or too broad. However, what Sharky has mentioned should give you some clues (@Sharky).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some templates can be set to desktop mode or responsive mode.

If you need website visitors to switch between these, you could install one of these templates, make a copy of the template and set one to responsive and one to non-responsive.

You could then install a template switcher to switch between them. There are free template switchers such as:

[Template Selector](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/template-selector)

[CG Template Switcher](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/cg-template-switcher)

Comment: I'll accept this as correct answer, I didn't know you had to use templates and whatnot. I was thinking maybe you could just do it through css settings or something that sets correct screen size.